# Custom UITableViewCell Creates issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

**Overview**
I'm creating a `UITableView` with custom `UITableViewCell` (in iOS 8.4,Objective-C). i've created `IBoutlets` of each and every items in Custom Cell. it seems working well, but randomly my UIButton gets disappeared from custom cell.

> here my CellForRowAtIndexPath Code

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   linkCell*cell = (linkCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if(!cell){
        cell = [[linkCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    NSDictionary *aDict = [numberOfSections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSDictionary* info = [[aDict objectForKey:@"Data"]objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    static float span = 5;
    static float dateviewsize = 83;
    static float linesize = 1;
    static float descriptionsize = 65;
    
    //DAY_NAME
    NSString* string = [self getDayNameFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"copied_url_date"]];
    cell.lblDayName.text = string;
   
    //DAY_NUMBER
    string = [self getDayNumberFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"copied_url_date"]];
    cell.lblDayNumber.text = string;
   
    //DAY_TIME
    string = [self getTimeFromDate:[info valueForKey:@"copied_url_date"]];
    cell.lblDayTime.text = string;
    
    //Link Label
    if([[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_title"] isEqualToString:@"nil"]){
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info valueForKey:@"copied_url"]];
        cell.lblLink.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_LIGHT size:14];
        cell.lblLink.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:51.0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:135.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }else{
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_title"]];
        cell.lblLink.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_MEDIUM size:16];
        cell.lblLink.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
    cell.lblLink.text = string;

    float w,h,y;
    w = self.view.frame.size.width-(span*2);
    CGRect dataviewframe,titleRect,buttonviewrect,imageRect;
    CGSize newsize;
    [cell.lblDescreption setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_LIGHT size:16]];
    [cell.lblDescreption setNumberOfLines:3];
    [cell.linkimage setHidden:NO];
    
    if([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].isReachable){
        //Unspacified ImageView
        if([[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_img"]isEqualToString:@"nil"]){
            [cell.linkimage setHidden:YES];//hide image
            //make call to get image & title of Copied URL
            [self MakeCallAndSetImageToImageView:indexPath ToGetImageFromURL:[info valueForKey:@"copied_url"]];
            
            //new size of link title
            y = span+dateviewsize+span+linesize+1;
            if([[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_description"] isEqualToString:@"nil"]){
                [cell.lblDescreption setHidden:YES];//hide description
                //set dataview's new height
                h = span+dateviewsize+span;
            }
            else{
                [cell.lblDescreption setHidden:NO];//show description
                NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_description"]];
                [cell.lblDescreption setText:string];
                newsize = [self getStringHeightWithMaxWidth:w-(span*2) AndText:cell.lblDescreption];
                if(newsize.height > descriptionsize){
                    titleRect = CGRectMake(span,y,w-(span*2),descriptionsize);
                    //set dataview's new height
                    h = y+descriptionsize+span;
                }else{
                    titleRect = CGRectMake(span,y,w-(span*2),newsize.height);
                    //set dataview's new height
                    h = y+newsize.height+span;
                }
                [cell.lblDescreption setFrame:titleRect];
                
            }
            dataviewframe = CGRectMake(span,span,w,h);
            
            //set buttonview's new frame
            buttonviewrect = CGRectMake(span,h+span+2,w,50);
            
        }else{
            [cell.linkimage setHidden:NO];//show image
            //new size of link image
            y = span+dateviewsize+span+linesize+1;
            float imageH = [self SizeWithScaledToWidth:w-(span*2)].height;
            imageRect = CGRectMake(span,y,w-(span*2),imageH);
            NSString* imgurl=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_img"]];
            [cell.linkimage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgurl]];
            [cell.linkimage setFrame:imageRect];
            y = y+imageH+span;
            //new size of link title
            if([[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_description"] isEqualToString:@"nil"]){
                [cell.lblDescreption setHidden:YES];
                h = y+span;
            }else{
                [cell.lblDescreption setHidden:NO];//show description
                NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[info objectForKey:@"copied_url_description"]];
                [cell.lblDescreption setText:string];
                newsize = [self getStringHeightWithMaxWidth:w-(span*2) AndText:cell.lblDescreption];
                if(newsize.height > descriptionsize){
                    titleRect = CGRectMake(span,y,w-(span*2),descriptionsize);
                    //set dataview's new height
                    h = y+descriptionsize+span;
                }else{
                    titleRect = CGRectMake(span,y,w-(span*2),newsize.height);
                    //set dataview's new height
                    h = y+newsize.height+span;
                }
                [cell.lblDescreption setFrame:titleRect];
            }
            //set dataview's new frame
            dataviewframe = CGRectMake(span,span,w,h);
            
            //set buttonview's new frame
            buttonviewrect = CGRectMake(span,h+span+2,w,50);
        }
    }else{
        //NO INTERNET CONNECTION
        //hide link image
        [cell.linkimage setHidden:YES];
        
        //hide link title
        [cell.lblDescreption setHidden:YES];
        
        //set dataview's new frame
        h = span+dateviewsize;
        dataviewframe = CGRectMake(span,span,w,h);
        
        //set buttonview's new frame
        buttonviewrect = CGRectMake(span,h+span+2,w,50);
    }
    cell.dataview.frame = dataviewframe;
    cell.buttonview.frame = buttonviewrect;
    if([selectedRow isEqual:indexPath]){
        cell.buttonview.alpha=1;
    }else{
        cell.buttonview.alpha=0;
    }
    [cell.btnShare setHidden:NO];
    [cell.buttonview bringSubviewToFront:cell.btnShare];
    [cell.buttonview bringSubviewToFront:cell.btnOpen];
    [cell.buttonview bringSubviewToFront:cell.btnCopy];
    [cell.buttonview bringSubviewToFront:cell.btnDelete];
    
    [cell.btnShare addTarget:self action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnOpen addTarget:self action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnCopy addTarget:self action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [cell.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    
    [cell.btnShare setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnOpen setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnCopy setTag:indexPath.row];
    [cell.btnDelete setTag:indexPath.row];
    
    return cell;
}
```

> **here is my screen shots**
> [image]
>
> [image]

**Thanks in Advance** tell me if you want more info.

Comment: remove and try `if(!cell){
        cell = [[linkCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }`

Comment: put table view cell as custom cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, i found the mistake in my code. i was setting `buttonview` tag `indexPath.row` and also gave same to `button` tag. and when `DidSelectRowAtIndexPath` get called, i was doing,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    linkCell*cell = (linkCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([selectedRow isEqual:indexPath]){
        selectedRow = nil;
//this is where i'm mistaking.
        [[cell viewWithTag: indexPath.row]setAlpha:1];
    }else{
        selectedRow = indexPath;
//this is where i'm mistaking.
        [[cell viewWithTag: indexPath.row]setAlpha:0];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

so, i gave `-1` tag to `buttonview` and the problem is solved.

```
if([selectedRow isEqual:indexPath]){
            selectedRow = nil;
            [[cell viewWithTag: -1]setAlpha:1];
        }else{
            selectedRow = indexPath;
            [[cell viewWithTag: -1]setAlpha:0];
        }
```

by the way **thanks** for your **valuable** Tips and Advises.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing way too much in the `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method. It's good practice to give a custom cell a configuration method, like `-(void)configureCell`, where the content and lay-out of the cell will be defined. In other words, let the cell be responsible (as much as possible) for its content and lay-out instead of the tableview.

I guess this part causes problems:

```
if([AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].isReachable) {
    ...
}
```

Especially:

```
[self MakeCallAndSetImageToImageView:indexPath ToGetImageFromURL:[info valueForKey:@"copied_url"]];
```

I don't know the implementation of this method, but I have the feeling you have to look over there, as it can be a threading issue at retrieving the image you requested.

One more tip: the way you name your classes and methods doesn't always follow the Objective-C conventions. Check `linkCell` (class) and `MakeCallAndSetImageToImageView ...` (method).

Answer (score 0):

Possible layout broken. Try to capture view hierarchy. In Xcode: Debug > View Debugging > Capture View Hierarchy.

Also, method dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: always returns a valid cell. if(!cell){ ... } will never be executed, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this block of GCD, i think it will work.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        //Do data fetching and calculation
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

            //Update UI on main thread
        });
    });
```

Comment: where should i use this block of GCD?

Comment: Vats, I think it depends on you where you want to use, i.e. you can use it where you want to work with background thread and main thread, as i mentioned that you can do your calculation and fetching of data in DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT and update your ui on main thread.